# Deleting a row in one table should also delete the corresponding rows in another table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, erd

I have these tables: `station` and `water_types`. The user may only have one station, and if the user wants to delete the `station`, the corresponding `water_types` must also be deleted. In a station, there might be multiple `water_types`.

```
create table
  public.water_type (
    id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4 (),
    name text not null,
    price numeric(10, 2) not null,
    user_id uuid not null,
    constraint water_type_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint water_type_user_id_fkey foreign key (user_id) references auth.users (id) on update cascade on delete restrict
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create table
  public.station (
    id uuid not null default gen_random_uuid (),
    created_at timestamp with time zone null,
    user_id uuid not null default auth.uid (),
    ..other data...
    tel_no numeric null,
    delivery_mode text null,
    constraint station_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint station_user_id_key unique (user_id),
    constraint tation_user_id_fkey foreign key (user_id) references auth.users (id) on update cascade on delete cascade
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

Based on the table, this is how I planned to implement this:

I planned to compare the `user_id` that the `station` has with the `user_id` from the `water_types`. And if it matches, it will delete all the `water_types` with the matching `user_id`.

Is there any another approach to this that is better or would this already suffice?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorry, it was `water_types`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a foreign key constraint to `water_types` that will do what you want:

```
ALTER TABLE water_types
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES station (user_id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE;
```